# how to convert array of String into array of object in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

How can I do aggregations to split the values inside the "assets" into individual objects?

This is my current object:

```
   [
      {
        "_id": ObjectId("5c949609ff5e3d6119758730"),
        "assets": [
          "one##two##three##four",
          "one##two##hello##world"
        ]
      }
    ]
```

Expected:

```
[
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5c949609ff5e3d6119758730"),
    "assets": [
        {
            "firstkey": "one",
            "secondkey": "two",
            "thirdkey: "three",
            "fourthkey": "four          
        },
        {
            "firstkey": "one",
            "secondkey": "five",
            "thirdkey: "hello",
            "fourthkey": "world         
        }
    ]
  }
]
```

How is it possible to use aggregation in MongoDB and spilt the values inside "assets" Array of String into Objects? firstkey, secondkey, thirdkey, fourthkey, are they possible to define in the aggregation query?

Comment: Why do you want it as firstkey secondkey instead of key1, key2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this :

```
db.collection.aggregate([
{
 $addFields: {
  assets: {
    "$map": {
      "input": "$assets",
      "as": "s",
      "in": {
        obj: {
          "$map": {
            "input": {
              "$split": [
                "$$s",
                "##"
              ]
            },
            "as": "a",
            "in": {
              v: "$$a"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
 }
},
{
$addFields: {
  assets: {
    "$map": {
      "input": "$assets",
      "as": "a",
      "in": {
        $map: {
          input: {
            $range: [
              0,
              {
                $size: "$$a.obj"
              }
            ]
          },
          as: "idx",
          in: {
            $mergeObjects: [
              {
                $arrayElemAt: [
                  "$$a.obj",
                  "$$idx"
                ]
              },
              {
                $arrayElemAt: [
                  {
                    "$map": {
                      "input": {
                        "$range": [
                          0,
                          {
                            $size: "$$a.obj"
                          },
                          1
                        ]
                      },
                      "as": "key",
                      "in": {
                        k: {
                          "$concat": [
                            "key",
                            {
                              "$toString": "$$key"
                            }
                          ]
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  "$$idx"
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  }
 },
 {
"$addFields": {
  "assets": {
    "$map": {
      "input": "$assets",
      "as": "a",
      "in": {
        "$arrayToObject": "$$a"
      }
    }
   }
  }
 }
 ])
```

Explained:
This will give you key0,key1 etc ...
afcourse if you want you may provide and map hard coded array with ["one","two","three"..]

[Playgorund](https://mongoplayground.net/p/v2vbsEPb8F8)

And here is with hardcoded array of strings as keys :

[Playgrouund2(arrayOfKeyStringHardCoded)](https://mongoplayground.net/p/_lloC7DInEM)

( only 5x elements , but you can extend as per the needs )

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for the help! may I check with you whether is it possible to convert any of the field's data type? field inside the array of object.

Comment: It is possible , but in the example above there is no too much posibilities ...